# How to delete old Alfresco Audit entries?

Tags: curl, alfresco, audit

This is the curl request I am using to clear audit entries:

```
curl -u admin:admin -X POST "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/audit/clear/{AuditExampleLogin1}?fromTime={2014-03-07T17:26:51.325+05:30}&toTime={2014-03-10T10:01:33.970+05:30}"
```

but this deletes all the audit entries, I can see that when I do

```
curl -u admin:admin "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/audit/query/AuditExampleLogin1?"
```

And the audit clear curl request does not delete from the database. Why and which entries does it delete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an open issue regarding clearing audit data from database. Currently, the audit clear request "only" clears the link between the data fragments that make up an audit entry (alf_audit_* tables), so it can no longer be found but the data still exists in the database (alf_prop_* tables). See https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/MNT-10067 for the open issue.

Comment: Thankx alot for pointing it out, was searching for solution badly. Is it best practice to delete from database using sql queries? Or is there anyway that would be proper to delete old entries?

Comment: Until a solution is provided by Alfresco, you can only use SQL queries to clear audit entries. I have written up a script for PostgreSQL to do that: https://gist.github.com/AFaust/7513792

Comment: Note: MNT-10067 has been implemented it seems.

Comment: Yes - MNT-10067 has been generally available for a while. Care should be taken if that job is to be run against a large database with lots of entries (collected over years). It is a single-threaded, single-transaction cleanup routine that can take quite a long while to complete and will lock the tables while it is running. I have recently implemented an incremental cleanup job that I hope the customer will allow me to provide to the community at some time...